# HTML multipart form - maximum length of "boundary" string?

Tags: html, http, mime-types

In a multi-part (i.e. `Content-Type=multipart/form-data`) form, is there an upper limit on the length of the boundary string that an HTTP server should accept?

As far as I can tell, the relevant RFCs say 70 chars:

- **RFC2616** (HTTP/1.1) section "3.7 Media Types" says that the allowed types in the Content-Type header is defined by **RFC1590** (Media Type Registration Procedure).
- **RFC1590** updates RFC-1521(MIME).
- **RFC1521** says that a boundary "must be no longer than 70 characters, not counting the two leading hyphens".
- The same text also appears in **RFC2046** which supposedly obsoletes **RFC1521**.

So can I be certain all the major HTTP/1.1 browsers out there today adhere to this limit?  Are there any browsers (or other HTTP clients/libraries) known to break this limit?

Is there some other spec or common rule-of-thumb I'm missing that says the string will be *shorter* than 70 chars?  In Chrome(ium) I get something like this: `----WebKitFormBoundaryLu4dNSGEhJZUgoe5`, which is obviously shorter than 70 chars.

I'm asking this question because my server is running in an extremely memory-constrained environment, so "malloc a buffer large enough to hold the entire header string" is not an ideal answer.

Comment: You ask for an upper limit. Of course it is possible that you do not get the full upper limit but less (related to the Chrome boundary).

Comment: there should be no problem if you use AJAX and process the data in your PHP file directly

Comment: “hold the entire header string”? Why the entire header, if you just need the boundary?

Comment: Why not allocate as much memory as the actual input requires? Use an upper limit of 70 bytes and reject larger boundaries as mal-formed.

Comment: @RobertSiemer - I asked about this 5 years ago....  But from what I recall, I had no `malloc` at all.  It was all statically allocated, fixed sized buffers, common on super trimmed down embedded environments. This was on an STM32 Cortex M3/4? part, with LwIP as the TCP stack and maybe 32-256 KB (as in kilobytes) of RAM? Redesigning the system today would make this question largely irrelevant, as the target price point of the board could now get a system designed to run Linux with thousands of times the RAM and a "real" webserver and a fraction of the development time.

Comment: @RobertSiemer - As a concrete example of the falling hardware cost, this was originally asked right around the time the Raspberry Pi Rev A was available for $35 USD, and you couldn't build a low-qty (a few thousand?) Linux board *much* cheaper than that.  The Pi project only pulled it off due to high volume.  Today, the Pi Zero would do everything we needed 10x over and goes for $5 USD.  Ultra low-power (microamps standby current) applications, or *extremely* high volume stuff would be the only reasons I'd do a project like this today, professionally anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you note, [RFC 2046](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt) updated the MIME spec, but kept the restriction of the maximum boundary string to 70 characters, not counting the two leading hyphens.

I think it's a fair assumption that the spec is followed by all major browsers (and all MIME-using clients, like mail programs) since otherwise passing around multipart data would be very risky indeed.

To be sure, I've experimentally verified it for you using the latest versions of:

- curl: `----------------------------5a56a6c893f2` (40)
- Chrome 30 (WebKit): `----WebKitFormBoundarym0vCJKBpUYdCIWQG` (38)
- Safari 6 (WebKit, and same as Chrome): `----WebKitFormBoundaryFHUXvJBZwO2JKkNa` (38)
- FireFox 24: `---------------------------7096603861379320641089344535` (55)
- IE 10: `---------------------------7dd1961640278` (40) - same technique as curl!
- Apache HttpClient: `-----------------------------1294919323195` (42)

Thus not only does every major browser/client conform, but all would allow you to save 15 allocated bytes per boundary per buffer from the theoretical max. If you could trivially switch on user agent, you could squeeze even more performance out. ;-)

Comment: Switch on user-agent? Are you serious?